# jQuery highlight plugin cancels text selection, making copy impossible while also rendering links unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I'm using the [jQuery Highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) to select some text on a web page.

I've hooked up selecting and deselecting with mouse events:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', doSelect);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', doDeselect);
```

The functions are:

```
function doSelect() {
    var selectionRange = window.getSelection();
    var selection = selectionRange.toString();
    if (selection.trim().length > 0) {
        $('body').highlight(selection);
    }
}

function doDeselect() {
    $('body').unhighlight();
}
```

Short and easy. The library searches for the selected text and wraps each occurrence in a `<span>` and so the text stands out.

It's working great, but I have two issues with how it behaves.

1. The problem is that once the `span` elements are applied, I cannot click hyperlinks (the ones that were found/selected), they don't react to clicks (I have to deselect the text first).
2. Once the `span` elements are added, the original selection is somehow lost, i.e. I cannot copy what I selected with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

These issues can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyw2aqw4/).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

### The code

The working demo is available here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyw2aqw4/16/)

JavaScript

```js
var $body     = $('body');
var $copyArea = $('#copyArea');
document.addEventListener('mouseup',   doSelect);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', doDeselect);
document.addEventListener('keydown',   keyPressHandler);

function keyPressHandler(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 67) {
        $copyArea.focus().select();
    }
}

function doSelect() {
    var selectionRange = window.getSelection();
    var selection = selectionRange.toString();
    if (selection.trim().length > 0) {
        $copyArea.val(selection);
        $body.highlight(selection);
    }   
}

function doDeselect(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).parents('a');
    if(elem.length == 0) {
        $copyArea.val('');
        $body.unhighlight();
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
Sample text to select.
<br/>Sample text to select.
<br/>Sample text to select.
<br/>google.com
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <span>
        <span>google.com</span>
    </span>
</a>

<textarea id="copyArea"></textarea>
```

CSS

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: #FFFF88;
}
#copyArea {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-999px; 
    height:0px;
}
```

### Part 1 - Clicking through the selection

Presumably, the reason clicking on a highlighted link doesn't work is because the process that disables the highlighting kicks in first and cancels the click.

To bypass that, we implement a condition that checks if the target element of the `mousedown` event has an `a` element as ancestor. If that is true, we simply do not execute `$body.unhighlight();`, allowing the click to pass through and open the link.

```js
function doDeselect(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).parents('a');
    if(elem.length == 0) {
        $copyArea.val('');
        $body.unhighlight();
    }
}
```

### Part 2 - Copying the selection

Presumably, again, the reason the selection is lost is because the document is modified by the highlighting, which introduces elements into the DOM.

My first idea was to reapply the selection after the modification was done. This became annoying and I went in a different direction, which allowed me to stumble upon this:

[The Definitive Guide to Copying and Pasting in JavaScript](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/)

This offered a simple and efficient idea: using an hidden element that could contain selectable text.

Therefore, to allow copying the selected text that we highlighted despite having lost the original selection:

1. We add a hidden `textarea` element to our document.

   ```js
   <textarea id="copyArea"></textarea>
   ```
2. We get a reference to that element.

   ```js
   var $copyArea = $('#copyArea');
   ```
3. We add an event handler for the `keydown` event.

   ```js
   document.addEventListener('keydown',  keyPressHandler);
   ```
4. We add the event handler.

   ```js
   function keyPressHandler(e) {
       if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 67) {
           $copyArea.focus().select();
       }
   }
   ```
5. We modify `doSelect()` to add some logic that will set the selection as the value of the `textarea` element, in the form of `$copyArea.val(selection);`.

   ```js
   function doSelect() {
       var selectionRange = window.getSelection();
       var selection = selectionRange.toString();
       if (selection.trim().length > 0) {
           $copyArea.val(selection);
           $body.highlight(selection);
       }   
   }
   ```

What does the handler do ? it captures the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and focuses on the text in the hidden textarea, which ends up being copied by the keyboard command we just issued.

Comment: Thank you - this is indeed a step in the right direction (where things do work).

The trick with links - works perfect. As for selection - it does not work :( I tried to copy / select and I only succeeded in about 30% of attempts.. Try it yourself - select by double clicking, select by actual selection of mouse etc..

Comment: @user3073853 This could be browser dependent, Firefox never missed a copy. This is probably just a timing issue. I'll think of something.

Comment: Thank you - I am interested in Chrome mostly, so it's easier to spot issues

Comment: @user3073853 Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE. Simply needed to listen to `keydown` and use `keyCode`.

Comment: Thank you - it indeed seems to work now! (will +50 once the system allows me to)

Comment: @user3073853 There's no hurry. Funny thing is, I planned to answer this soon after you posted but worked on another answer for a while. You would have gotten this for free if you had waited one more day.

Comment: you deserve this bonus, because it just .. works now! Thanks again!